# Optimizing Web Crawling

Tags: c#, image, performance, webclient

I am working on a quick tool that grabs images off of a web page. Currently, I use a WebClient to get the source data of the page, parse the image URLs out of the source, and download them individually to a folder using WebClient.DownloadFile. This can take quite a while.
I understand that most of the time needed is due to my connection and downloading the data.
 Are there any other, more efficient ways of going about this, whether it be a C# HTML parsing library or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple threads, which will open multiple concurrent HTTP connections to the web page.

One good approach would be to implement a Producer/Consumer pattern: have one thread that gets and parses the HTML containing the images, then queues the image URLs into something like a BlockingCollection.  Have multiple threads read the image URLs from the queue and download the images concurrently.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx

If you're up for cutting edge, this class if problem is ideally suited for TPL Dataflow (alternative to a BlockingCollection).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx